# Unable to use any browser Lubuntu/Xubuntu 14/16.04

Tags: firefox, google-chrome, crash, browser

Hello I have a problem that I hope somebody can solve.

I and a friend of mine tried to install Xubuntu 16.04 / 14.04 and then Lubuntu 16.04 / 14.04 but after many attempts we are still unable to use Firefox or any other browser normally.

[this is the crash report from Firefox](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GSq0B.jpg)
[this is the output from the Terminal](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Q3Cmd.jpg)

Interestingly we found that in "Try mode" from the Live USB stick we were able to use Firefox or Chrome and there were no crashes.

So please if somebody know how to solve this problem and help my friend to use his old computer for browsing.

Comment: Will you edit your message and add the errors that you get when you run **Chromium**?  You can install it with `sudo apt install chromium-browser`.  Also will you show the output of running **Google-chrome**?  Finally, the text output that you showed in the image.  Will you add that as text to your question.  It'll make it easier to copy and paste it into a Google search to see how the message has been dealt with by others.  It'll also help if you would click on the **Details** button of the first image.  If it has text that can be copied, please copy and paste that text to your question also.